# HEXtoDEC with Text ouput issue

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, format, hexadecimal

I am using Excel 2010 and performing a hextodec conversion with text appended to end.

If I have a HEX value of `00B60000` that is located in cell `D3` and apply the formula `=SUM(((HEX2DEC(D3)*32)/1024)/1024)&" MB"` I get the expected result of `364 MB`.

If I have a HEX value of `00B5995A` that is located in cell `F3` and apply the formula `=SUM(((HEX2DEC(F3)*32)/1024)/1024)&" MB"`  I get the result `363.198059082031 MB` which is mathematically correct, but I do not want all the decimal places.

I have tried all the default formatting options to the cell, including without decimal places, and the result is the same.  Additionally, I have tried to clear contents of the cell and have copied the format from the cell that works correctly to the one that does not work correctly to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROUND` function, with 0 decimal places:

```
=ROUND(((HEX2DEC(D3)*32)/1024)/1024,0) & " MB"
```

Another solution, would be to keep the results stored as numbers, and show with "MB", using this formula:

```
=(((HEX2DEC(E3)*32)/1024)/1024)
```

and applying this custom formatting: `0 "MB"`